# How to Load custom page between place-order-click and thank-you-page in magento

Tags: magento

hi,
    Can any one tell me,how to load custom page between checkout onepage & Checkout success page in magento? Reply as soon as possible.

Thanx.
Krupa Parikh

Answer (score 0):

It could be hard as after clicking 'place order' form is send to checkout controller and if no redirect to payment gate is required magento redirects to checkout success page. If you need some custom redirect you need to hook into `controller_front_send_response_before` event and change the response (but first check the action as this is general event fired by every action and every controller).